How to handle clients connections of unknown format and length in the OnExecute method of Indy IdTCPServer
If I have:
procedure TFServer.IdTCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  ...
  size:=AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLongInt;
  Context.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(msgStream, size);
  ...
end;

it is all ok if my client send data with IdTCPClient.IOHandler.Write(MemoryStream1,0,True) but if the client send data with IdTCPClient.IOHandler.WriteLn(string_message) the IdTCPServer crash trying to execute Context.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(msgStream,size).
I also tried with Context.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(msgStream,-1) and nothing changed.
Obviously I don't mix these calls but I would like to know how to properly handle this type of problem in case of malicious clients. More generally, how can you properly handle clients sending data of unknown format and length?


if the client send data with IdTCPClient.IOHandler.WriteLn(string_message) the IdTCPServer crash trying to execute Context.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(msgStream,size).

That is because the client is not sending a valid integer to denote the message length.  If the client uses IOHandler.WriteLn() then the server should use IOHandler.ReadLn() to receive it.

More generally, how can you properly handle clients sending data of unknown format and length?

Your clients and server need to agree on the messaging format in order to communicate properly.  If clients are misbehaving and not following the established format, you could simply let them crash and the server will disconnect them for you.
If you really need to handle misbehaving clients more gracefully, then your only real course of action is to simply read arbitrary bytes from the socket and then parse the bytes yourself looking for things that you are not expecting.
Using IOHandler.ReadStream(msgStream,-1) will not work for this task, because that will try to read an integer from the socket and then read the specified number of bytes.  However, IOHandler.ReadBytes() with AByteCount=-1 should work.  Alternatively, you can call IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource() to buffer whatever is currently in the socket, and then call IOHandler.ReadStream() or IOHandler.ReadBytes() with AByteCount set to IOHandler.InputBuffer.Size to read everything from the buffer.

Ok, I thought there was a correct way unknown to me to handle these problems but I will try your solutions and in the worst case I will read chunks of data and then parse them to know what to do. Thanks
